# this a code from dash ploltly. x is not getting value of input1 in action url '/charts/{x}'

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

```
app.layout = html.Div(dcc.Graph(
            id='example-graph',
            figure = fig,
    ),
    
    html.Form([
    dcc.Input(id='input1', name='name'),
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit', type='submit'),
    ], action=f'/charts/{x}', method="POST"),#pass value to /charts/{x} x as target value
])

@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('submit', 'n_clicks')],
    [dash.dependencies.State('input1', 'value')],
)
def update_output(n_clicks, input1):
```

#if clicked then put value in x
if n_clicks!=None:
global x
x = input1
return x

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to go to some url "localhost://charts/England" where England replaces x which is submitted from input form.